# how to access value in tcl script from .cc files

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

I'm trying to get value from .cc. In my file ,
 AgentCPU.h and AgentCPU.cc
there is a integer called "npkts_" and a function "recv" for receive Packets
when I finally finished a packet , I will increase the "npkts_" 1
In further , in my tcl script I want to access the "npkts_"
my code is like this

```
set cpu [new Agent\AgentCPU]
puts [format "%d" "$cpu set npkts_"]
```

However , ther value is not correct
it is same to the value when I construct my AgentCPU like this

```
AgentCPU::AgentCPU(): Agent(PT_TASK)
{
...
npkts_=199;
...}
```

the value will be 199,
and in the "recv" function , I use "printf" to check if there is any problem

```
...
npkts_++;
printf("npkts is %d\n",npkts);
...
```

and the value here is correct,every time I receive Packet will increase the "npkts"
Is there any code wrong?? 
On the other hand, I use another way to debug
In my "recv" function

```
...
npkts_++;
Tcl& tcl = Tcl:;instance();
tcl.evalf("puts \" npkts is %d""",npkts_);
..
```

In this way the message will be 1, and stop to print 
Can sombody give me a hand?
How to get the correct value from .cc file?
Any suggestion will be very thankful!!

Comment: Did you find a way to get the variable's value in tcl script?
If so, let me knw please. 
I am counting packets in recv function, I am displaying it as well, but want to perform some other operation on the value in tcl script.

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl, every script evaluation produces a result value (which could be the empty value, or could be something else, depending on what happened). That result value may be retrieved from the interpreter context with `Tcl_GetStringResult` or `Tcl_GetObjResult`; the former produces (effectively) a `const char *` and the latter a `Tcl_Obj *` (i.e., a Tcl value reference; the name `Tcl_Obj` is for historical reasons). That value is there until the next piece of script is evaluated. Do not modify the `Tcl_Obj*` returned (except via Tcl's API) unless you know exactly what you're doing (i.e., are writing code to extend Tcl itself). Integers may be efficiently retrieved from a `Tcl_Obj*` using `Tcl_GetIntFromObj` (assuming that the value is an integer), floating point numbers with `Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj`, and a `const char *` can be retrieved from a `Tcl_Obj*` using `Tcl_GetString` or `Tcl_GetStringFromObj` (slightly different API).

There are also variables in Tcl. You can read those directly with `Tcl_GetVar` — which returns another `const char *` — or `Tcl_GetVar2Ex` (with an ugly name but convenient API) that returns another `Tcl_Obj *`.

---

These are all C API functions and all take a `Tcl_Interp *` (which is a reference to a Tcl evaluation context, which is *always* bound to a single thread). How they have been wrapped in the C++ API… I can't tell you that.

Comment: Thanks alot! But I think my problem is not in getting value.
Cause my goal is trying to let two node one is host with traffic generator and another is client.And the packet sended by host will be send back by client.Since the calculation is in host ,and it looks like the client didn't send the packet back. So the information I need in the host will be the default value..

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question :( and thanks for trying help me

Answer (score 0):

You are using some weird C++ library you are not giving any information about. However, when using Tcl from a C/C++ program when you evaluate some Tcl code the result is available attached to the interpreter object. You access this using [Tcl_GetObjResult](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/SetResult.htm) and then use an appropriate Tcl_GetIntFromObj or Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj or whatever to read the Tcl_Obj value into some C++ form.

Comment: sorry for not provide enough information.
I'm writing a ns simulation use "mytcl.tcl"
and I want to access some vriables which is declared in MyAgent.cc
, the new Agent with a receive function

Comment: And really sorry that could you comment more clear.. I'm not sure what's your mean..:(
Is the Tcl_GetObjResult a tcl script to access the variables value in c++ file (MyAgent.cc)?